# Convenient error analysis

Tags: numerics, core-language

Is there any convenient way to find out the error in evaluating an expression numerically, providing all errors of the arguments are given? Like

```
Sin[DataError[123, .1] + 3*DataError[456, .2]/DataError[789, .5]]^2
```

> `DataError[xxx, xx]`

Comment: You might consider using `Interval[]` for this application.

Comment: What would be the form of the result you have in mind?

Comment: @DanielLichtblau , like what's written above, plug in all tuples of data and it's error, giving out a tuple of result and calculated error (according to error analysis and pde stuff)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was not stated how `DataError` is to be defined, and in particular whether the second argument is to be taken as an absolute or relative error. I am assuming absolute.

Easiest is, as suggested by @J.M., to use `Interval`.

```
dataError1[a_, b_] := Interval[{a - b, a + b}]
val1 = Sin[
   dataError1[123, .1] + 3*dataError1[456, .2]/dataError1[789, .5]]^2

(* Out[580]= Interval[{0.542555735765, 0.736481835669}] *)
```

Could use explicit optimization to avoid the "dependency problem" (which does not arise in this example).

```
dataError2[a_, b_, eps_] := a + b*eps
val2 = Sin[
    dataError2[123, .1, eps1] + 
     3*dataError2[456, .2, eps2]/dataError2[789, .5, eps3]]^2;

evars = {eps1, eps2, eps3};
NMinimize[{val2, Thread[-1 <= evars <= 1]}, evars]
NMaximize[{val2, Thread[-1 <= evars <= 1]}, evars]

(* Out[584]= {0.542555735765, {eps1 -> 1., eps2 -> 1., eps3 -> -1.}}

Out[585]= {0.736481835669, {eps1 -> -1., eps2 -> -1., eps3 -> 1.}} *)
```

If the error offsets are fairly tight, could do this as a first-order estimate. Much better for speed, in complicated cases.

```
firstorder = 
 Normal[Series[val2 /. Thread[evars -> t*evars], {t, 0, 1}]] /. t -> 1
NMinimize[{firstorder, Thread[-1 <= evars <= 1]}, evars]
NMaximize[{firstorder, Thread[-1 <= evars <= 1]}, evars]

(* Out[586]= -0.095854777084 eps1 - 0.000728933666038 eps2 + 
 0.00105321214104 eps3 + Sin[32805/263]^2

Out[587]= {0.544829012526, {eps1 -> 1., eps2 -> 1., eps3 -> -1.}}

Out[588]= {0.740102858308, {eps1 -> -1., eps2 -> -1., eps3 -> 1.}} *)
```

Answer (score 3):

One could use the built-in arbitrary precision numerics, I suppose.  I don't know the accuracy of [`Accuracy[]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Accuracy.html), but it seems to be close if an approximate error is what is desired and not hard bounds.  The smaller the relative error, the better it will be.  Accuracy is measure on a log-10 scale. See also [`SetAccuracy[]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetAccuracy.html).

```
Sin[SetAccuracy[123, 10^-.1] + 
   3*SetAccuracy[456, 10^-.2]/SetAccuracy[789, 10^-.5]]^2
% + {1, -1} Log10[Accuracy[%]]
(*
  0.*10^-1
  {0.549593, 0.735339}
*)
```

We can see from the `0.*10^-1`, whose `FullForm` is
`` 0.642465935417333765`0.6153213200244898 ``, is that one drawback is that the error can overwhelm the computed value.  If it does, *Mathematica* will return a value of zero and this method will fail.